# how to force DPI settings in Xenial?

Tags: gnome, xorg, lightdm

Is it possible at all to force a specific DPI settings in Ubuntu Xenial?

Recipes mentioned in [Can I pass a dpi flag to lightdm to set the proper DPI for X?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/72486/can-i-pass-a-dpi-flag-to-lightdm-to-set-the-proper-dpi-for-x) don't work anymore:

- I can successfully pass `-dpi...` option to X server,
- I do see in `Xorg.0.log` that X server uses that option (actually without this option it successfully calculated proper DPI from monitor physical dimensions),
- but even on the login screen DPI settings are set back to 96, according to `xdpyinfo` (I've checked this with an xterm, launched from a text console with  proper `$DISPLAY` and `$XAUTHORITY` manually set).

So the question is: is changing DPI possible at all? Or should I simply dump off anything related to GNOME (due to this ["WONTFIX"](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=757142)) until more sane developers come to the GNOME team?

Comment: Close voters: what the hell does this have to do with the development version of Ubuntu?

Comment: From what I can tell, the GNOME developers have been bitten by the same stupid bug as Microsoft, and signed on with just treating all monitors as if they are the same 96 DPI of the original 14 inch VGA CRTs.  If you can find a way to work around this and use proper DPI, I would be very much interested.

Comment: Got exactly the same problem here. would be happy if you got a solution

Comment: There's a bug report that seems to be related, if everybody says `it affects me too` the importance goes up and it should get fixed sooner: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gtk+3.0/+bug/1543546

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't test on Xenial at the moment, but here's a fix that worked for my DPI-related problem on Trusty when none of the others did.

**Problem:** When I rebooted after having to swap out one of my 19" 1280x1024 monitors for a 17" 1280x1024 monitor, my fonts were small and looked "wrong" (I lack the vocabulary to say more but I assume it had to do with how the anti-aliasing interacted with a bad DPI setting).

Worse, GTK+ 2.x apps gave the confusing impression that they were ignoring the font size settings. (If I changed the font face or style, applications would update, but not even restarting applications would cause a change from 11pt. to 12pt. or 14pt. to have any visible effect. I didn't test that symptom against GTK+ 3.x though.)

**Solution:** The `Xft.dpi` X11 resource.

**Confirmed effective for:** GTK+ 2.x, GTK+ 3.x, and Qt 4 apps

For your case, try running this on your system and then restarting your applications:

```
echo Xft.dpi: 75 | xrdb -merge
```

**Note:** You may need to wait and/or restart them twice. When I tested GTK+ 3.x with `file-roller` and a DPI of 144, it remained on the 144 scale the first time I tested it after setting my DPI back to 96, but quitting and restarting it a second time returned it to the expected scale.

If that solves the problem, persist it by adding `Xft.dpi: 75` on a line of its own in `~/.Xresources`.

If it doesn't solve it, try again with other values to make sure you understand what the system is doing with the value you give it. I had to set the DPI to 96 to get the desired scale and that didn't occur to my sleep-fogged mind until I tried 72 DPI and the font shrunk rather than growing.

(Replacing the failed left-most 19" monitor with a 17" monitor was an online replacement and I have KDE's display settings daemon disabled, so what I expected was all three monitors operating on a fixed DPI setting calculated from a 19" 1280x1024 display.)

If the `~/.Xresources` version has no effect, your desktop is probably missing the customary call to `xrdb` to apply them. I typically add `xrdb -merge ~/.Xresources` as one of the last things to run on login so it doesn't conflict with whatever else the desktop may be trying to accomplish.

Comment: Perfecto! This works perfect on Ubuntu 22.04 using i3wm. Thanks a lot! Weeks looking for a solution and when tried this I get what I have. All the best!

Answer (score 0):

you can set your dpi directly using xrandr whilst running

```
xrandr --output <outputname> --dpi <dpi>
```

or in the /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf file

```
xserver-command=X -dpi 75
```

and see that is accepted using

```
xdpyinfo | grep resolution
```

Not all combinations of drivers and screen outputs support DPI scaling , if you can't do it on the command line its unlikely that lightdm will be able to do it.

You will also find some applications (particularly older or not native gtk) will not look right at non-standard DPIs and in some cases are totally unusable. This should get better over time as higher dpi screens become the norm.

Comment: `xserver-command=X -dpi 75` doesn't work, see above