# How do i change the dpi in ubuntu 16.04 - Unity?

Tags: 16.04

How do I change the dpi in Ubuntu 16.04 using Unity?  I have searched several times but am finding answers for older version and not sure how relevant they still are.  I see the option to scale menu sizes but want to try adjusting the DPI itself.

Comment: Try [here](http://onetransistor.blogspot.com.ng/2014/09/change-dpi-in-ubuntu.html) and [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/753018/how-to-force-dpi-settings-in-xenial) for information on if its possible

Comment: welcome glad to have been of help.